# Why is UNNotificationContent's attachments property an NSArray (vs a single UNNotificationAttachment)?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, unnotificationattachment

Why is the `attachments` property for `UNNotificationContent` an array as opposed to a single `UNNotificationAttachment`? It appears that only the first attachment is used as a preview in Notification Center...

Are additional attachments only useful as a way of passing along metadata to a custom VC interface, or does it serve some other purpose? The documentation specifies that multiple attachments can be specified but isn't clear as to their purpose.

Answer (score -1):

you can force touch on these notifications. I know when you attach a video and force touch... it plays the video.

So I'd guess when you attach multiple media items, it must show the rest "inside"